# font change just works for partial of a page

Tags: fonts, thesis

I have the following written in my permeable for my dedication page:

```
\newcommand{\dedicationpage}{
   \newpage \thispagestyle{plain} 
   \font\chan=pzcmi at 12pt
   \vspace*{\fill}
   \begin{center}
   \scshape 
   \chan \input{frontmatter/dedication}
   \vspace*{\fill} \newpage \rm
   \end{center}
}
```

And my dedication page has the following:

```
{\textbf{Dedicated \protect\\ to}}
\newline
\vspace{10mm}
{this is the first line \protect\\ and this is the second line}
```

And it turns out only "this is the first line and this is the second line" works in the designed font, but not the ”Dedicated to“ part. Could you help point out what the problem is here? Thanks!

Comment: Whoever suggested you to use `\font` should be banished from using LaTeX. `;-)`

Comment: i got it from here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25249/how-do-i-use-a-particular-font-for-a-small-section-of-text-in-my-document. down at this page, there are a few lines of code....

Comment: It is worth underlining that `\textbf{}` isn't like the little B button in Microsoft Word and does not, by default, fake bold. What it does is use the typeface that is specified as bold, so you have to use a font which has a bold version, or you must declare some other bold face for use by `\textbf{}`.

Comment: That's code for Plain TeX, not for LaTeX.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know where you found out that code; but `\font` should ***never ever*** be used in a LaTeX document.

```
\documentclass{book}

\newcommand{\dedicationpage}{%
  \clearpage
  \thispagestyle{plain}% better empty
  \vspace*{\fill}
  \begin{center}
  \usefont{\encodingdefault}{pzc}{m}{n}
%  \input{frontmatter/dedication}
  %% here I insert directly the code
  Dedicated \\ to \\[10mm]
  this is the first line \\
  and this is the second line
  %%
  \end{center}
  \vspace*{\fill}
  \clearpage
}

\begin{document}

\dedicationpage

\end{document}
```

Here I type the text in the command definition just not having to create directories and files. Note that `\textbf` is meaningless in that context, because Zapf Chancery has no boldface version.

The input file, if you want to use it, should be

```
Dedicated \\ to \\[10mm]
this is the first line \\
and this is the second line
```

and, in this case, the definition would be

```
\newcommand{\dedicationpage}{%
  \clearpage
  \thispagestyle{plain}% better empty
  \vspace*{\fill}
  \begin{center}
  \usefont{\encodingdefault}{pzc}{m}{n}
  \input{frontmatter/dedication}
  \end{center}
  \vspace*{\fill}
  \clearpage
}
```

[image]

Comment: i don't know why but when I copy your code and past in my file, I didn't get what you get, but just plain default font on my page...

Comment: @Yvonne Check for warning in the log file. What TeX distribution are you running?

Comment: overleaf online...I downloaded this thesis template from Harvard here: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/tagged/harvard#.WFbMU7YrJPU

Comment: i just change your code "\usefont{\encodingdefault}{pzc}{m}{n}" into "\usefont{OT1}{pzc}{m}{n}", and it worked!